# Confidence intervals and central estimates for a functional of an estimated function with uncertain parameters

Tags: bayesian, optimization, posterior, credible-interval, bayesian-optimization

I've got a problem that is leading me to dip my toes into Bayesian stats, and I've got a question about confidence (or, I suppose, credible) intervals:

Say you want to know how $X$ maps to $y$.  You fit a model $y=f(X)+\epsilon$.

Then, you want to optimize $X$ to get the best $y$: 
$$y_{max} = argmax_X(\hat{f}(X),s.t. \text{whatever constraints}) $$

This gives you the model's best estimate of the optimal $X$ for getting the biggest $y$.

But obviously $\hat{f}(X)$ is uncertain.  If you take a Bayesian standpoint that $\beta$ is distributed multivariate normal, you can take samples from it, which gives new coefficients (see, for example, [this](http://people.bath.ac.uk/sw283/mgcv/check-select.pdf)).  Taking many samples, using them to pick new optimal values of $X$, one gets a distribution of $y_{max}$ that reflects uncertainty in $\hat{f}(X)$.

Here is the problem:  the central estimate of $y_{max}$ (i.e.: optimizing based on the parameter estimates of the fitted model) is not necessarily the mean or the median of the $y_{max}$ distribution that one gets when optimizing the functions based on the posterior draws.

So what should I do with the "central estimate"?  Which estimate should I consider to be my "best guess" of the value of $y_{max}$?  Should it be $y_{max}$ at the (ML) parameter estimates?  Should it be the mean or median of the posterior simulations of $y_{max}$?

I don't know whether there is a right answer here:  maybe this is a somewhat of a philosophical question?  (Or am I making some relatively fundamental mistake, which makes my whole question moot?  If so, I'd be grateful for replies that point it out.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimization when Cost Function Slow to Evaluate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate)